# How to print selected Table Element within the same window?

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I am working on a [simple executable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Vl5a.png) which allows me to select a table element.

Currently, when i select a table element, it produces a [popup notifying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcvAH.png) that i have selected the particular element

However, i wish to [print the element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2on7.png) out in the large empty space next to the table each time i select an element, however the solutions i found didn't exactly fit what i have in mind. Is there a solution to my predicament?

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

choices = ('Windows Enterprise 10','Windows Server 19','MacOS','Ubuntu','Debian')

layout = [  [sg.Text('Pick an OS')],
            [sg.Listbox(choices, size=(20, 5), key='-OS-', enable_events=True)] ]

window = sg.Window('Pick an OS', layout,size=(500,200))

while True:                  # the event loop
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    if values['-OS-']:    # if something is highlighted in the list
        sg.popup(f"The OS you selected is: {values['-OS-'][0]}")
window.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

choices = ('Windows Enterprise 10','Windows Server 19','MacOS','Ubuntu','Debian')
layout = [[sg.Text('Pick an OS')],
            [sg.Listbox(choices, size=(20, 5), key='-OS-', enable_events=True), 
            sg.Text(key='OUT', size=(30,5), text_color='#000000',background_color='#ffffff')]]

window = sg.Window('Pick an OS', layout,size=(500,200))

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    else:
        choice = values['-OS-']
        window['OUT'].update(f'You have selected:\n{choice}')
window.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Put another element to show the result beside your `sg.Listbox`, then update that element with value of `sg.Listbox`. Element can be `sg.Text` which need to split message to lines by yourself, or `sg.Multiline`.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

choices = (
    'Windows Enterprise 10',
    'Windows Server 19',
    'MacOS',
    'Ubuntu',
    'Debian',
)

sg.theme('DarkBlue3')
sg.set_options(font=("Courier New", 12))

layout = [
    [sg.Text('Pick an OS')],
    [sg.Listbox(choices, size=(22, 5), key='-OS-', enable_events=True),
     sg.Text('', size=(40, 2), font=("Courier New", 12, 'bold'), key='-OUTPUT-')],
]

window = sg.Window('Pick an OS', layout)

while True:                  # the event loop
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == '-OS-':
        text = f"You have selected: {values['-OS-'][0]}\nOperating System"
        window['-OUTPUT-'].update(value=text)

window.close()
```